# black box script execution?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, simulation

I have a client that would like to examine results of a script I have written. I don't want the client to see the inner workings of the script or I lose my value to them but I want them to be able to run it as many times as they want and observe the results.

I am not sure if there is a general solution to this or specific to a language. If the latter applies, I have scripts in Python and R.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about writing scripts outputs to files ,and construct a web interface that consumes this files and displays them in read-only mode?

For example in R you can use 
    sink() 
to route the output messages to a file, you then construct a web interface that simply displays this file.

Comment: I have not heard of the sink() function before so it is a nice suggestion. I suppose writing a simple shiny app is also a possibility too.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can easily use Flask to provide a restful API that the client can send their HTTP request with their parameters and you can provide them with the results.

It is very easy to convert a Python function into a web server. It is as easy as this function:

```
@app.route('/geo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def geo_web():
    '''
    RESTful API
    given a piece of text, vectorize it, classify it into one of the regions using clf (a pre-trained classifier) and return a json which has info about the predicted location(s).
    '''
    text = request.args['text']
    if isinstance(text, list) or isinstance(text, tuple) or len(text) == 0:
        return
    result = None
    try:
        result = geo(text, return_lbl_dist=False)
    except:
        return
    return jsonify(**result)
```

You just need to add the @app.route... and return a result that can be processed when the HTTP response is read.

You can see my entire project in [here](https://github.com/afshinrahimi/pigeo).

Comment: Your project looks really interesting! While I need to look a bit more into Flask, I think it may be a bit too much for the client and maybe building a simple gui would be better.